# Playframework's selenium test fails with flash.success

Tags: playframework

I used Selenium to verify for the present of a flash.success message after submit a form (kind like 'New user has been created successfully') , I used verifyTextPresent(..) but sometimes it works fine and sometimes it doesn't, It's been working fine all the time on manually test but fails sometimes on Selenium test.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it could be related to Selenium Tester clears the flash every 2 seconds or so. See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786824/problem-with-flash-scope-play-framework).